# How can I use a native DLL from C#?

Tags: pinvoke, native-code

Given a native DLL, with no documentation or anything, and assuming it is not a COM component, is there any way to extract some sort of interface from that DLL so it can be called from C#?

I know about PInvoke, but that requires me to already know the method names and signatures. I don't have those.

Is it even possible?

Comment: If method signatures are exported, there are tools you can use to read them then use P/Invoke to interop with the dll. Otherwise you're going to have to figure out some other way of finding "entry points" and invoking them. Probably have to do that with C++/CLI or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a PE reading tool to list the exported functions. For example [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) will do that for you.

There's not a right lot you can do with that information though. There's no metadata with a native DLL that tells you how to call those functions, what their signatures are. Or even what the parameters represent.

Something has gone wrong with this project. A DLL on its own is not enough. You need a header file and some documentation.

Comment: No, nothing is wrong with the project. I'm really conducting a fact-finding exercise to work out whether the project is feasible in spite of a non-cooperative third party. It looks like the answer is no - so plenty of time saved :)